# It is Possible to Generate Access Token without using Username and Password?

Tags: refresh, access, username

There is any way to generate Access Token Without Using Username and Password not even login on web form also ? Just Using Client Id ,Client Secret or other rather than including password  Using REST API.

I also tried OAuth Web Server API flow and OAuth User Agent API flow can issue a refresh and access token but the user has to go through an Browser to login and authorize the App. So you agree with me it's not so much user-friendly for a Customer. So, there is any way to remove this login and Authorization part.

It is mandatory to  use Username and Password to get Access or Refresh Token using REST API ?

There is one more question it is possible to  get access token any time using Refresh token ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a possibility.

What I understood so far, is that your needs are some server-server integration without additional interaction of the user.

[OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) is perfectly designed to your needs.

> Sometimes you want to authorize servers to access data without
> interactively logging in each time the servers exchange information.
> For these cases, you can use the OAuth 2.0 JSON Web Token (JWT) bearer
> flow. This flow uses a certificate to sign the JWT request and doesn’t
> require explicit user interaction. However, this flow does require
> prior approval of the client app.

In this flow generated private key and certificate is used as a security element instead of a password.

Make sure, that you'll be able securely to store your private key.

For other flows,  in settings for the connected app, you can set a period, when the refresh token is expired, or never expires. JWT Bearer Flow never issues a refresh token.